# Missing index file Brackets IDE

Tags: css, html, brackets, adobe-brackets

This is a question which I'm not fully understanding. I need further insight and I have been unable to find it elsewhere.

Hello everyone. I'm getting an error in the brackets IDE that looks like this [http://imgur.com/WccBRtf](https://imgur.com/WccBRtf) . I don't understand at all what's going on here, and that's because I don't know what an HTML5 index file really is. The file I have named index.html is just the main HTML5 code for a webpage I wan't to run. The file is as follows

```
<head>
    <!-- Title of webpage -->
    <title>

        Name of Guild

    </title>

    <!-- Link the CSS file so that the html5 can display it --> 
    <link rel = "Stylesheet" type = "text/CSS"  href = "GuildPageStyle.css">

</head>

<!-- Main Body of the page -->
<body>







    <!--Post section-->


    <div class = "PostsSEC">




        <!-- The way to display multiple posts is to go through a while loop counting up until all posts have been displayed with the current pots being displayed being equal to the current post in the while loop -->
        <p id = "PostMain">

            *A post*

        </p>

        <!--This is not the image, this is box it is in-->
        <p id = "PostPosterBoxOR">

            < ORIGINAL
            <br />
            POSTER

        </p>
        <p id = "PostPosterBoxBL">



        </p>

        <!--The next section is totally reliant on a server side language. This is the likes and votes by other powered members of the group-->





        <div id = "EndMessage">    
        <!-- Message at the end of the posts declaring that it is the end --> 
        <h1 id = "PostsEnd">

            That's all the current posts

        </h1>



        <!-- Change the something Missing to a link after completion -->
        <h3 id = "ErrorCheckPostEnd">

            Something Missing? 

        </h3>
        </div>


    </div>

    <!--Profile/Users/Follower barier-->
    <div id = "Bar">
    </div>

    <div id = "BackgroundBlock">
    </div>

    <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/64cUAcH.png" id = "GuildLogo" />

    <!--The group of users-->

    <div id = "Users">

    <!--Replace this section with PHP reliant on the users-->

    </div>

    <img src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/855649567756476416/OHQKYYvY_400x400.jpg" id = "ProfileOne" />

    <img src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/855649567756476416/OHQKYYvY_400x400.jpg" id = "ProfileTwo" />

    <img src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/855649567756476416/OHQKYYvY_400x400.jpg" id = "ProfileThree" />

    <img src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/855649567756476416/OHQKYYvY_400x400.jpg" id = "ProfileFour" />

    <img src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/855649567756476416/OHQKYYvY_400x400.jpg" id = "ProfileFive" />

    <img src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/855649567756476416/OHQKYYvY_400x400.jpg" id = "ProfileSix" />

    <div id = "BackgroundBlockade">
    </div>

    <p id = "BioBlock">
    This is a bio
    </p>

</body>
```

Now up until yesterday I was fully able to run the file in brackets. Then, for seemingly no reason from my perspective, I became unable to run the code. After it stopped working I changed the name of the HTML5 file to index.html and kept the CSS file exactly the same. I have no idea what's going on, and have been able to understand nothing.

I realize to the more experienced programmer this may seem like a question similar to "Why isn't this code running" when all that's wrong is that they forget to do "std::" instead of just writing out "endl". I'm very new to HTML5 and am completely lost here. I thank you for your time. Have a nice evening.

Here is another image to aid

[http://imgur.com/QELF7Ts](https://imgur.com/QELF7Ts)

(Yes I did try removing the "HTML5 guild page html.html")

Comment: The solution is easy. Either make sure your current folder has a index.html file or open the xxx html file in brackets and then click live preview,otherwise it will try to find your index.html by default.

Comment: Yeah no the problem is resolved. Thank you

Comment: I'm not correcting you. When I say yeah no I don't mean to sound like I'm not grateful for your response either. It's just how I say "Yeah, thanks, the problems fixed now"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have resolved the issue. By opening the project as a folder instead of one singular file at a time i managed to succeed in resolving it. Problem solved